# Gulp divide one file in several

Tags: gulp

The problem is that that I need to divide my gulpfile in several file.  Now I use something like this

```
'use strict';
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var performTasksInStrictOrder = require('gulp-sequence');
    var del = require('del');
    var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

    function getTask(task) {
        return require('./gulp-tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins);
    }

gulp.task('img-make', getTask('img-make'));

gulp.task('make-sprites', performTasksInStrictOrder(
    ['img-make']
));
```

The divided file looks like this

```
module.exports = function(gulp, plugins) {
    return function() {
        gulp.src([
            './app/fonts/*.ttf'
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/fbstax-theme/fonts/'));
    };
}
```

On this stage everything is fine. But I want to make something like this

```
gulpfile.js
--make-sprites.js
----sprite1.js
----sprite2.js
----sprite3.js
```

In fact, I have too much these separate files with sprites and main gulp file is still long. How will look the gulp file of the second level? The third level will look as mentioned above but what about the second one? Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md  It looks like most of it is simplified for you.

Comment: yeah,but I would like to split it with module.export.